# How to compile the example of APRON?

Tags: c, compilation

I am trying to understand how to work with [APRON](http://apron.cri.ensmp.fr/library/) .

The first thing I thought about doing is to compile the [C example](http://apron.cri.ensmp.fr/library/0.9.10/example1.c)
 in the "Documentation" section in the above link.

Can someone please help me out ? I didnd't manage to understand how to compile the example

Any help is greatly appericiated!

Answer (score 1):

You need rest of the source code for the library, which is linked at the bottom of that page, i.e.: http://apron.cri.ensmp.fr/library/apron-0.9.9.tgz